# selection history from "shortest path"?

Tags: python, bmesh

is it possible to retrieve the selection history(the specific sequence) of vertices selected using "shortest path"?

Using bmesh, I can get the selection history by doing:

```
vertlist = [elem.index for elem in bm.select_history if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMVert)]
```

But this unfortunately only works for verts, that have been manually selected(by hand and via "next active").

If anybody has any insight into this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: The answer is correct? if is, please check as correct. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this script will help you

```
import bpy, bmesh

print("*"*50)
oa = bpy.context.active_object
obj = bpy.context.object

bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select() #add for request

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)


v1,v2 = [elem for elem in bm.select_history if isinstance(elem, bmesh.types.BMVert)]

list = [v1]
verts = len([v.index for v in bm.verts if v.select])

cont=0

while cont< verts:
    v=list[cont]
    edges = v.link_edges

    for e in edges:
        if e.select:
            vn = e.other_vert(v)
            if vn not in list:
                list.append(vn)

    cont+=1

print(list)

for v in list:
    print(v.index)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me, True)
```

[image: selection history from shortest path]

Comment: Have you forgotten to put in the shortest path operator call before you populate verts?

Comment: @batFINGER the answer is ok? if is, please check as correct please. best

Answer (score 1):

the script is modified based on @yhoyo.In edit mode, given the start vertex index and the end vertex index, index_order store the shortest path

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
start_index = 5017 # start points 
end_index = 2045 # end points
bm.verts[start_index].select = True  
bm.verts[end_index].select = True  
bpy.ops.mesh.shortest_path_select()
verts_list = [bm.verts[start_index]]
verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
cont=0
while cont< len(verts):
    v=verts_list[cont]
    edges = v.link_edges

    for e in edges:
        if e.select:
            vn = e.other_vert(v)
            if vn not in verts_list :
                verts_list.append(vn)
    cont+=1
index_order = [v.index for v in verts_list]
for v in verts_list:
    print(v.index)
```

Comment: Hi and Weclome! Can you please explain (at least a bit) what you've changed?