# How to know whether vertex array is clockwise or unclockwise

Tags: python

I referenced python code to change vertex array with clockwise from
[How can I sort vertex positions sequentially indices in a closed area?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/191649/how-can-i-sort-vertex-positions-sequentially-indices-in-a-closed-area)

Most plane change with clockwise very well, but some plane change with unclockwise!

I want to align array of planes, so is it possible to check whether vertex array is clockwise or unclockwise, and if its array is unclockwise, then use the python code again.

Comment: I wonder the same, I use bpy.ops.object.convert(target='CURVE', keep_original= False)
bpy.ops.object.convert(target='MESH', keep_original= False) but most plane change with clockwise very well, but some plane change with unclockwise and I wonder how to determine this.